# How to Display Attribute Group Name in Product Tab Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento2

I created an attribute set and attribute groups with attributes in it. In the admin panel the attributes are listed in groups, like i created them. But on the front productpage all the attributes are listed together, without displaying the attribute group name first.
I would like to display the **Attribute Group Name** on the **product page** (more information tab), before the attributes in this group. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this by default in Magento 2.

There are a few ways I can think of to acheive this. Perhaps best would be to extend the `getAdditionalData()` method in `/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php` so that it adds the attribute group name (or id) to the returned array.

You would then need to create a local copy of `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml` and iterate the array returned by the modified `getAdditionalData()` method sorting it according to the group name and then output the data with group name headings.

I'd be interested to hear of other or best practice approaches to this type of relatively simple extended functionality in Magento 2.